# PHP - how to access/view image from Firebase Storage?

Tags: php, firebase, storage

I am saving the image using Firebase PHP SDK. I have successfully uploaded multiple image to the Firebase Storage. My problem is I can't read from Firebase Storage as it access requires token and I have to manually generate access token from Firebase interface. So now how I can view / access the image from my website? Now I'm getting broken image.

[image]

Comment: You can find an implementation example at https://github.com/jeromegamez/firebase-php-examples/blob/master/src/Command/UploadFileCommand.php

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to access it**

$bucketname={Your bucket name from your storage}

$folder={Folder inside bucket} in yourcase **profile_images**

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/".$bucketname."/o/".$folder."%2F".$filename
```

**if you want to view it**

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/".$bucketname."/o/".$folder."%2F".$filename"."?alt=media"
```

Comment: also read , https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/254